# How avoid ambiguousness when joining tables with a where statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a query such as

```
SELECT * 
FROM bookings  
left JOIN answers on bookings.id=answers.booking_id 
where id=1
```

since both tables have id and booking_id i am getting : `column reference "id" is ambiguous`

Comment: `where bookings.id = 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qualify the column references -- *all* of them.

To facilitate this, use table alias that are abbreviations of the table names.  Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM bookings b LEFT JOIN
     answers a
     ON b.id = a.booking_id 
WHERE b.id = 1;
```

(Note:  I don't know if you want `b.id = 1` or `a.id = 1`, but the latter condition should be in the `ON` clause for a `LEFT JOIN`.)

I would also advise you to list out the columns in the `SELECT` -- you have duplicate names so you want to be careful there too.

Answer (score 1):

use alias

```
SELECT a.* ,b.*
FROM bookings  b
left JOIN answers a on b.id=a.booking_id 
where a.id=1
```